# QPushButton.setMenu (self, QMenu menu) using code generated from Qt Designer

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I am trying to create a Pop-Up push button using Qt5 Designer tool. I designed the gui in qt designer and then using pyuic5 converted it .py file. But I cannot seem to change the default push button added by drag-and-drop using qt designer into a pop styled button that when clicked will give me options such as Bar,Scatter,Box Plots. What I want to do is create a pop-up button that will give the options Bar,Scatter,Box and when i choose the respected option, the label changes to a loaded image. The code is as below :

```
# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'adcombo.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(6, 10, 791, 361))
        self.label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.WinPanel)
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 430, 231, 91))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 0, 0);\n"
"background-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);\n"
"font: 75 16pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.comboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 430, 301, 91))
        self.comboBox.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 0, 0);\n"
"background-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);\n"
"font: 75 16pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.setItemText(0, "")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        self.comboBox.addItem("")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.comboBox.setVisible(False)
        self.comboBox.currentTextChanged.connect(self.on_combobox_changed)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onclick)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Chart Type"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(1, _translate("MainWindow", "Bar"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(2, _translate("MainWindow", "Scatter"))
        self.comboBox.setItemText(3, _translate("MainWindow", "Box"))

    def onclick(self) :
        self.comboBox.setVisible(True)


    def on_combobox_changed(self) :
        if self.comboBox.currentText()=='Bar' :
            bar = QPixmap('bar.png')
            self.label.setPixmap(bar)

        if self.comboBox.currentText()=='Scatter' :
            scatter= QPixmap('scatter.png')
            self.label.setPixmap(scatter)

        if self.comboBox.currentText()=='Box' :
            box = QPixmap('box.png')
            self.label.setPixmap(box)
            #self.label.setText('Line Chart')

        if self.comboBox.currentText()=='' :
            self.label.clear()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Any and all help will be appreciated.

Thanks

**UPDATE 1**
I want to edit the above code to have a button like the one in the picture below.

[image: Desired Button Output]

Comment: I do not understand you, you could explain me better pointing maybe with an image what you get and another what you want to obtain. Also in what part do you use setMenu()?

Comment: Well i didn't use setMenu() anywhere because I could not figure out how to use it and that is what i need help with. I updated the post with the image of what kind of button i need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a QMenu, set the QActions and use the triggered signal to know that QAction was pressed.

```
# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'adcombo.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPixmap

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(6, 10, 791, 361))
        self.label.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.WinPanel)
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 430, 231, 91))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 0, 0);\n"
"background-color: rgb(79, 79, 79);\n"
"font: 75 16pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Chart Type"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.create_menu()

    def create_menu(self):
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(
            self.pushButton, 
            triggered=self.on_menu_triggered
        )
        for text in ("", "Bar", "Scatter", "Box"):
            menu.addAction(text)
        self.pushButton.setMenu(menu)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtWidgets.QAction)
    def on_menu_triggered(self, action):
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap()
        if not action.text():
            self.label.clear()
            return
        if action.text() == 'Bar':
            pixmap = QPixmap('bar.png')
        elif action.text() == 'Scatter':
            pixmap= QPixmap('scatter.png')
        elif action.text() == 'Box':
            pixmap = QPixmap('box.png')
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Upvoted the answer. Works perfect. One last thing, any good sites to understand pyqt gui development and to get better at it? I am learning pyqt5 but man there is no complete guide from which I can learn from. I still dont understand any part of the code that you added :(